# SQL query constrain returns for column of a JOIN LEFT table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to constrain the return of the query and the value I'm constraining for comes from a `JOIN LEFT`. My approaches sof far failed.

Thos are the tables `user` and `verification`:

```
+----+------------+
| id | first_name |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Alex       |
|  2 | Marc       |
|  3 | Cath       |
+----+------------+

+----+---------+-------------+--------+
| id | user_id | verified_at | status |
+--------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | 1       | 2018-01-02  | done   |
|  2 | 2       | (NULL)      | open   |
|  3 | 3       | 2018-02-02  | done   |
|  4 | 4       | 2018-01-02  | done   |
|  5 | 5       | (NULL)      | open   |
|  6 | 6       | 2018-02-04  | done   |
|  7 | 7       | (NULL)      | open   |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
```

Here is the initial query without constraining for the verified_at date

```
SELECT

  u.id,
  u.first_name,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.verified_at) as verified_at,

  FROM users as u

  LEFT JOIN verification as v on (v.user_id = u.id and v.status = 'done')

  group by u.id
```

Database architecture and this query have not been done by me. Personally, I think that if the column status is always 'done' when a date is set is somewhat redundant. But that's how it is at the moment.

**My first question** is about the `v.status = 'done'` part of the query. It does not seem to do anything, as the query let's all users pass to the return. Not only users with status done. So what's the idea behind this constain?

**Second**, I try to manage to filter for a certain verification date. I tried the obvious:

```
SELECT

  u.id,
  u.first_name,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.verified_at) as verified_at,

  FROM users as u

  LEFT JOIN verification as v on (v.user_id = u.id and v.status = 'done' and v.verified_at >= '2018-01-01')

  group by u.id
```

Which does not filter the return. Neither does `v.verified_at IS NOT NULL`.

I also tried to put it to `WHERE` or `HAVING` giving me alerts about undefined columns all the time.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the `group by`.

The following gets a list of all users with their verified date, if any:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.verified_at) as verified_at,
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     verification v 
     ON v.user_id = u.id and v.status = 'done';
```

If you want only users that are "done", then change the `JOIN` from a `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.verified_at) as verified_at,
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     verification v 
     ON v.user_id = u.id and v.status = 'done';
```

Comment: The query is actually way longer than I posted. E.g. there is a `GROUP_CONCAT` involved. I think that requires the group by. But I have to learn about it to know what it does exactly. Meanwhile, is there a way with the `group by`?

Comment: @agoldev . . . Yes, but you need to use aggregation functions for the non-key columns.